# Multi Valued Choice Functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Wikipedia gives the definition of a choice function: [Choice Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_function)

as some function defined on a collection $X$ of non empty sets that takes each set $S$ in $X$ and assigns it to some element $f(S)$ in $S$.

Eg: $X = \{\{1,4,7\}, \{9\}, \{2,7\}\}$

$f(\{1, 4, 7\}) = 7$ , $f(\{9\}) = 9$,  $f(\{2, 7\}) = 2$

Here $f$ is a choice function.

My question is, is there a multi valued choice function? i.e instead of choosing a single element choose a subset? For eg: in the above case can we have $f(\{1,4,7\}) = \{1,7\}$

Is this still a function ? Does it have a special name?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Can you explain why not, why can't we think of it as a function that takes one set which can be considered as an element of the power set and maps it to another set, which is also an element of the same power set?

Comment: By definition, function has a unique value given one input element so that multi valued function is not a function.

But we could define a function to map a set S into a subset of of S such as $f(\{1,4,7\})=\{1,7\}$. But the function is not choice function.

Comment: It is a function, but taking values in $\mathcal P(S)$ rather than $S$.

Comment: I doubt that it has a special name.